# Crossar.io authentication failed and connection dropped on trying got Handshake with Autobahn

Tags: wamp, crossbar, autobahnjs

I got theses errors while implement login (with wampcra) using Autobahn JS to Crossbar.io:

```
2018-04-13T09:04:34-0300 [Router       6948] failing WebSocket opening handshake ('This server only speaks WebSocket subprotocols wamp.2.cbor.batched, wamp.2.cbor, wamp.2.msgpack.batched, wamp.2.msgpack, wamp.2.ubjson.batched, wamp.2.ubjson, wamp.2.json.batched, wamp.2.json')
```

and

```
2018-04-13T09:04:34-0300 [Router       6948] dropping connection to peer tcp4:127.0.0.1:53586 with abort=False: This server only speaks WebSocket subprotocols wamp.2.cbor.batched, wamp.2.cbor, wamp.2.msgpack.batched, wamp.2.msgpack, wamp.2.ubjson.batched, wamp.2.ubjson, wamp.2.json.batched, wamp.2.json
```

I think this is an Autobahn version issue.

```
Version:     Crossbar.io COMMUNITY 17.11.1
```

Answer (score 0):

How I had suspected the Autobahn was updated.

Solution:
Re install the autobahn.

Remove your AutobahnJS:

```
npm un autobahn -S
```

Install the latest AutobahnJS:

```
npm i autobahn -S
```

```
 $ npm i autobahn -S

+ autobahn@18.3.2
updated 1 package in 8.259s
```

And try to connect to Crossbar again.

```
2018-04-13T09:04:02-0300 [Controller   6943]      __  __  __  __  __  __      __     __
2018-04-13T09:04:02-0300 [Controller   6943]     /  `|__)/  \/__`/__`|__) /\ |__)  |/  \
2018-04-13T09:04:02-0300 [Controller   6943]     \__,|  \\__/.__/.__/|__)/~~\|  \. |\__/
2018-04-13T09:04:02-0300 [Controller   6943]                                         
2018-04-13T09:04:02-0300 [Controller   6943] Version:     Crossbar.io COMMUNITY 17.11.1
2018-04-13T09:04:02-0300 [Controller   6943] Public Key:  xxxxxxxxx
2018-04-13T09:04:02-0300 [Controller   6943] 
...
2018-04-13T09:04:36-0300 [Router       6948] failing WebSocket opening handshake ('This server only speaks WebSocket subprotocols wamp.2.cbor.batched, wamp.2.cbor, wamp.2.msgpack.batched, wamp.2.msgpack, wamp.2.ubjson.batched, wamp.2.ubjson, wamp.2.json.batched, wamp.2.json')
2018-04-13T09:04:36-0300 [Router       6948] dropping connection to peer tcp4:127.0.0.1:53610 with abort=False: This server only speaks WebSocket subprotocols wamp.2.cbor.batched, wamp.2.cbor, wamp.2.msgpack.batched, wamp.2.msgpack, wamp.2.ubjson.batched, wamp.2.ubjson, wamp.2.json.batched, wamp.2.json
....
2018-04-13T09:06:04-0300 [Router       6948] session "6143323932507538" joined realm "realm1"
```